# How to use action buttons to show and hide table output in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

In the below simple App code, I generate a user input table (or matrix) inside a Shiny modal dialog. Clicking the "Modify" action button pulls up a default user input table where the user can modify the default values, insert/delete input columns, etc. "Show" action button pulls up `table2` in the main page, "Hide" hides that same table. (You can ignore the `table1` that appears in the modal box, that's temporarily there for testing purposes, to be deleted later). "Reset" button reverts the table back to the default table.

Problem with this is "Show" and "Hide" work only once. Also, after having modified the input table (or matrix), clicking "Modify" pulls up the default table and not the most recently modified table.

So, how would I modify the below so that (i) clicking "Show" and "Hide" respectively show and hide the most recently modified table, repeatedly (OK to have a combined Show/Hide button too, using shinyjs `toggle` function, something I have toyed with), (ii) clicking "Modify" the first time the App is invoked pulls up the default table (as it currently does) but subsequent clicks of "Modify" pull up the most recently modified table, and (iii) clicking "Show" without having first modified the table pulls up the default table?

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix3Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              label = 'Series terms:',
              value = matrix(c(1,24,0,1),4,1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)), 
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,names = TRUE), 
              cols = list(extend = TRUE,names = TRUE,editableNames = TRUE,delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric") # close matrix input
} # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Inputs"),
  fluidRow(actionButton("modify","Modify"),
           actionButton("show","Show"),
           actionButton("hide","Hide"),
           actionButton("reset","Reset"),
           tableOutput("table2")
  ) # close fluid row
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{showModal(modalDialog(
    matrix3Input("matrix"),
    tableOutput("table1"))
    )})
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable(input$matrix, rownames = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    tableOutput("table2")
    output$table2 <- renderTable(input$matrix, rownames = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$hide,{hide("table2")})
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    tableOutput("table2")
    output$table2 <- renderTable(input$matrix, rownames = TRUE)
  })
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should cover for all the different scenarios.

I have used `reactiveValues` to save `matrix3Input` and matrix.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)


default_mat <- matrix(c(1,24,0,1),4,1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))

matrix3Input <- function(x, default_mat){
  matrixInput(x, 
              label = 'Series terms:',
              value = default_mat, 
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,names = TRUE), 
              cols = list(extend = TRUE,names = TRUE,editableNames = TRUE,delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric") # close matrix input
} # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Inputs"),
  fluidRow(actionButton("modify","Modify"),
           actionButton("show","Show"),
           actionButton("hide","Hide"),
           actionButton("reset","Reset"),
           tableOutput("table2")
  ) # close fluid row
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(mat = matrix3Input("matrix", default_mat), input = default_mat)
  hide("table2")
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat,
      tableOutput("table1"))
    )
    hide("table2")
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    rv$mat <- matrix3Input("matrix", input$matrix)
    rv$input <- input$matrix
    input$matrix
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    show("table2")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$hide, hide("table2"))
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    hide("table2")
    rv$input <- default_mat
    rv$mat <- matrix3Input("matrix", default_mat)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    rv$input
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, when I run your code, table2 doesn't appear when I click the "Show" button. And each time I click "Show", the only that happens is the following is returned in the R studio console: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6025
[1] "table2"

Comment: Just checked again on fresh new R session. It works fine for me and shows/hides/resets correctly. Not sure what might be going wrong at your end.

Comment: Yes, restarting R did the trick. Works great. I'll study your fixes. Thank you Ronak!!

Comment: Any idea how I can make a rendered table hide after making changes to selectioninput or actionButton?